# How to access data from within a key

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to access a data object that is referenced by a key. In this case, we have "applicant" data nested within an Event. I'm trying to create a new object with that data. I can access top-level Event data and the key for each applicant, but I can't figure out how to access applicant data - for example, application date, notes, and status.

I'd like to say something like applicationStatus = key.status, but that doesn't work.

```
onCreateApplication () {
  fb.eventsCollection.orderBy('startDate', 'desc').onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
  let appsArray = []

  querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
    let event = doc.data()
    let eventId = doc.data().id
    let eventTitle = doc.data().title
    let eventSlug = doc.data().slug
    let applications = doc.data().applicants
    let appStatus = doc.data().applicants.status
    for (var key in doc.data().applicants) {
      let eventData = {
        id: eventId,
        title: eventTitle,
        slug: eventSlug
      }
      let userData = {
        id: key
      }
      let application = {
        event: eventData,
        user: userData,
        status: key.status????????,
        appliedDate: key.created??????
      }
      fb.applicationsCollection.add(application)
    }

  })


  })
},
```

Comment: What do you mean `I'd like to say something like applicationStatus = key.status, but that doesn't work.`? What errors are you getting?

Comment: This is confusing: let applications = doc.data().applicants; let appStatus = doc.data().applicants.status; Is .applicants an object or an array? Can you share a json object of doc.data()?

Comment: David, there's a lot inside of doc.data()... Here's the top part that also shows "applicants" acceptedSegment: 2322209
addWaiver: ""
ageRequirement: "18"
applicants: {01YsU8aPIfPd725ygJLGUmbnmOk2: {…}, 0DgIQ0mGYmO2frPpylS6gmvSjPP2: {…}, 0Fhg4qX8QTZKBdxVdvjdWHSKqpe2: {…}, 0qLbz6n7whQSphbPplVLjwzQjlP2: {…}, 0rnOT3DUqudNXv7zjGF6wvOFons1: {…}, …}
appliedSegment: 2322213
barbacks: true
bartenders: true

Comment: Then within "applicants" is each application:

Comment: applicants:
0DgIQ0mGYmO2frPpylS6gmvSjPP2:
createdAt: "Tue May 15 2018 19:50:54 GMT-0700 (PDT)"
date: "Sat May 19 2018 16:20:26 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)"
dropped: "Fri May 25 2018 16:55:31 GMT-0700 (PDT)"
media: true
note: ""
shift: "fullTime"
signature: "Marcello Sanchez III"
status: "DROP"
waiver: true

Comment: Again, if you post the errors you are getting you are much more likely to get a correct answer. `applicationStatus = key.status` is valid javascript as long as `key` is an object with a property called `status`. So not sure what your issue is.

Answer (score 0):

This is my best guess as to what is going on with your data structure. I hope this helps and please comment to clarify anything else.

```
onCreateApplication(){
  fb.eventsCollection.orderBy('startDate', 'desc').onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      let data = doc.data();    
      let applications = Object.keys(data.applicants).map(function(id){
        let application = {
          event: {
            id: data.id,
            title: data.title,
            slug: data.slug
          },
          user: {
            id: id
          },
          status: data.applicants[id].status,
          appliedDate: data.applicants[id].created
        })

        fb.applicationsCollection.add(application);

        return application;
      })
    })
  })
}
```